# PHP: how do I know if a variable is a "::class?"

Tags: php

I have PHP code which passes a parameter as `User::class` which is then instantiated with `new $p`.

But I also need to be able to pass it a query instance ... a concrete instance of something which, of course, is also an object ... which is a member of a class.

Therefore, how do I detect whether the value of a variable was created using the `::class` nomenclature?

---

A little one-liner suggests an answer:

```
$ php -r 'class foo {}; print gettype(foo::class);'
string
```

Is this assumption correct?  An object instance (e.g. a query) would be of type `object` while a `::class` construct would be `string`?  Did I just answer my own question?

---

To clarify, my code wants to do this:

```
 if (gettype($q) == 'string') {
   $query = new $q();      // must be '::class' (TRUE in my situation tho' not generally)
 } else {                  // (so, the only other possibility in my case is 'object')
   $query = $q;            // existing object instance
 }
```

... and in *my* particular situation I know the parameter will always be one or the other.  I don't need a generalized solution.

Comment: what do you mean by query instance ?

Comment: I just edited the question to add a clarification of what I want to do.

Comment: that seems good . you have just to check if the class exist in case of string params (class_exists($q))

Answer (score 2):

The `foo::class` is a string and it's not different from other strings.

The `class_exists` function may help you:

```
    var_dump(class_exists(foo::class));
```

result: true

Comment: Thank you ... very good to know.  In *my* case I don't have to worry about it being "an errant string."

Comment: (duplicate comment)

Comment: @MikeRobinson your welcome. choose the answer if it was enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your options:

```
class Foo {
}

$foo = new Foo;

is_object($foo); // $foo is an object

is_string($foo); // No, $foo isn't a string

$foo instanceof Foo // $foo is an instance of Foo

is_string(Foo::class) // Foo::class is a string just like any other string

get_class($foo) // returns 'Foo'

class_exists('Foo') // returns true if class Foo can be found
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foo::class` call returns a string of the class name.  You could instantiate an object and feed it a variable like so:

```
$p = foo::class;
$query = new QueryThing();
$obj = new $p($query);
```

You could do this to see what type of class you have

```
get_class($p) // returns "foo"
$p instanceof foo // returns true
```

But you can't know that your object was instantiated dynamically from a `foo::class` call.

Comment: In my case, Captain, that's not what concerns me here.  I literally need to know if the parameter I've been passed *is a* `foo::class` ... which appears to be a `string` ... versus an instance of an object.  I believe that my `gettype()` test will work for my particular, restricted circumstances.

Comment: I just edited the original question to show what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Absent anyone hurrying up to tell me that I am mistaken, I'm going to say that "yes, for my purposes, I did answer my own question."  *(I edited the original question to show what I have in mind.)*

Comment: Seems correct. You would know better than us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can shoot for `instanceof`

```
if($q instanceof Foo){
    echo "Here do the things you need with your class";
} else {
    echo "Assume it is a string?";
}
```

The other option I would suggest is to make sure you get the data you expect with type hinting.

```
function bar(Foo $foo){
    //foo has to be Foo class or exception will be thrown.
}
```